# Simulate Keyboard Event

Tags: .net, events, keyboard, virtual, keypress

I am trying to insert string values to a third party application say, notepad. Below is the code that I am using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

public  void sim_type(string txt)
    {

        const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt);

        foreach (byte keyCode in ASCIIValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ascii Values = " + keyCode);
            keybd_event(keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            keybd_event(keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
        }


    }
```

I am giving a sample text message For example "This is a test Message".
I am getting the proper ascii values.
But in the target text box for the corresponding sample message I am getting this output.

> t89 9 1 13:38 02/12/2010513:38 02/12/2010 -5175

Could some one help to solve this. I am also putting the ascii values printed in console

> Messsage :This is a test message
>
> {
>      Ascii Values = 84
>
> Ascii Values = 104
>      Ascii Values = 105
>      Ascii Values = 115
>      Ascii Values = 32
>      Ascii Values = 105
>      Ascii Values = 115
>      Ascii Values = 32
>      Ascii Values = 97
>      Ascii Values = 32
>      Ascii Values = 116
>      Ascii Values = 101
>      Ascii Values = 115
>      Ascii Values = 116
>      Ascii Values = 32
>      Ascii Values = 109
>      Ascii Values = 101
>      Ascii Values = 115
>      Ascii Values = 115
>      Ascii Values = 97
>      Ascii Values = 103
>      Ascii Values = 101
>      }

Please Somebody help
Thanks,
Nikil

Comment: Here's an example of how to do that with [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has been superseded by [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I would recommend taking a look at the [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) which provides a nice C# Wrapper around the Send Input API. You can also simulate Mouse movements with the SendInput API (and something I believe they're working on for the next version of the Input Simulator).

I've used this library for an automation project and it seems to work pretty well, however there are some quirks (IE the keystoke HOME + SHIFT + END does not select all text as expected).

Comment: The above mentioned issue was actually resolved by myself submitting a patch here http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/workitem/13002 I still highly recommend this library for anyone looking for a nice managed interface to SendInput.

Answer (score 0):

keybd_event's first argument is a virtual key code, not an ASCII code. Some of the VK are same as ASCII (that's why you get the first t!), but this is not the way to do it.

One way to achieve what you want is to use the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method. To this method you can pass a KEYBDINPUT which has a field for passing Unicode characters (if you specify the KEYEVENTF_UNICODE flag).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me to identify my mistake. SendKeys is more easier way than what I did before.